# How can this xss challenge be solved?

Tags: xss

I found this :
http://research.insecurelabs.org/xssmas/

And so far my solutions were:

```
1.http://research.insecurelabs.org/xssmas/search.php?query=<script>alert(0)</script>
2. http://research.insecurelabs.org/xssmas/xssmas.swf?clickTAG=data:text/html,<script>alert(0)</script>
```

but there seem to be five solutions.Can anyone help me I'm trying to learn more about XSS.
thanks

```
UPDATED:

I know that two other solutions are related to this:
1.
<script>
var n = '';
if (n != '') {
    $(function() {
        $("h1").html("Merry XSSmas, " + unescape(n) + "!");
    });
}
</script>

2.


<script>
<!-- Analytics: no change below this line -->
document.write('<img src="analytics?url=">');
</script>

Update solved no2:

http://research.insecurelabs.org/xssmas/?url=maxa"><fake></script><script>alert(0)</script>
```

Comment: the point of a challenge is to test your skills...  asking for the solutions doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see where the solutions were asked for.  I see where it is stated there are 5 solutions, and I see a request for assistance.  Maybe someone pointing or "nudging" in the right direction would be possible?

Comment: I have updated my thread , just want to know how can I access those values.
Thanks

Comment: As the author behind the challenge, here are the intended solutions: http://research.insecurelabs.org/xssmas/solutions.html

Comment: Thanks the jquery one gave me a real headache , but three of 5 for a beginner is not bad, and btw nice challenge.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to learn, then asking for others to answer the question for you seems counter-productive.

Check out [cheatsheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) and other material to work through it all.

Comment: I have updated my thread , just want to know how can I access those values.
Thanks

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Yep. 2 years ago, the lines were drawn slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

While I strongly agree with everybody who said that since this is a challenge and you should solve it on your own, I have to say that this is, after all, a Q&A site. You have asked a question and, if I'm able to, I'll answer it. What you do with that answer is your own responsibility.

That said, I recommend that you only continue reading if you tried very hard and couldn't find an answer.

After some [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) I found that there's something interesting with `research.insecurelabs.org/xssmas/index/analytics`, it appears that anything passed to it (`analytics?SOMETHING`) is written here `document.write('<img src="analytics?url=SOMETHING">');`

Trying with `.../xssmas/index/analytics?<script>alert(0)</script>` yielded no result, so I decided to test the classic [`onerror`](http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2008/03/19/xss-with-img-onerror-attribute/):

```
.../xssmas/index/analytics?<img src="giveMe404" onerror="alert(0)">
```

And it worked.

Good luck finding the rest!

Comment: Thanks , I think first three were easy but others will be very hard , will try my best. Hvala

Answer (score 0):

> Trying with `.../xssmas/index/analytics?<script>alert(0)</script>` yielded no result, so I decided to test the classic onerror:

You should imagine how look like server page script... it could be sth like that:

`<script>
<!-- Analytics: no change below this line -->
document.write('<img src="analytics?url=<?php echo $variable; ?>">');
</script>`

Your example would work but you need "clear out" rest of unnecessary JS code - I mean: `">');`